# VT-x on Asus B85M-E motherboard

Tags: motherboard, vmware, virtualization, vt-x, vt-d

I have moved from Intel motherboard to new Asus B85M-E one. Now I'm trying to run my old virtual machines I have installed on Intel motherboard and can't run 64 bits systems. While running Linux virtual machine I have message

```
    This virtual machine is configured for 64-bit guest operating systems. However, 64-bit operation is not possible.

    This host supports Intel VT-x, but Intel VT-x is disabled.
...
```

Is it possible somehow run my old virtual machines in my new system?

Comment: Go to bios setting & enable visualization your problem may be solve

Answer (score 0):

you need to go into the bios settings on your motherboard and in advanced enable intel virtualisation technology or vt-x